# Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program - Powerpoint could not open in server

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint

Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program - Powerpoint could not open in server. It is working fine in local machine.

I used code :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();

Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;

Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation =
  multi_presentations.Open(
    Server.MapPath(path),
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse,
    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse
  );
```

Comment: Where isn't it working? is it possible that there is actually just not enough RAM in the computer this is failing on?

Comment: Powerpoint, like all Office programs, is highly unsuitable to be run on a server.  Use Task Manager, good odds you'll see dozens of copies of Powerpoint running.  This does end somewhere, the OS pulls the plug when the kernel memory pool runs low.

Comment: Thanks

This is working in my local machine. and I installed VS in server when i run the project in server it is also working but when it is run from iis it is giving error...

Comment: @D2ddeveloper and it would because there is only one instance of this. If this is running on a server, there could be many instances of this executing at one which is eating all the memeory

Comment: @HansPassant , I closed the application after read done.

Comment: The server detail is 2012 and ram is 64.0
Current in use :- 18.6

and just I noted Cached is 36.8.

Comment: The [documentation is very clear on this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) - **Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

Comment: Hi @stuartd, I used word read using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" in same project it is working fine. in server and local machine

Comment: @D2ddeveloper you got lucky

Comment: @SaggingRufus Server is 2012 and ram is 64.0.
Current in use :- 18.6 and 
just I noted Cached is 36.8. – Do you think it might be issue?

Comment: @D2ddeveloper could be, I would recommendation that you follow Microsoft's recommendation as they created it.

Comment: I installed office in server and it is working fine in debug mode

Comment: Hi all, Any other way to read Powerpoint file using c#.

Comment: Hi all, I changed my code. Now I am using "DocumentFormat.OpenXml",
but I am not able to create slidepart image. anyone can Help?